# A simple C++ trading system demo

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I need my trading system demo reviewed. It implemented a simple system which parse the trading flow (logged in file) of different trader and calculate some important feature.

**packets.h**

```
#ifndef PACKET_H
#define PACKET_H
#include <stdint.h>

class Header{
public:
    char marker[3];
    uint8_t msg_type;
    uint64_t sequence_id;
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint8_t msg_direction;
    uint16_t msg_len;
};

class OrderEntry{
public:
    uint64_t price;
    uint32_t qty;
    char instrument[11];
    uint8_t side;
    uint64_t client_assigned_id;
    uint8_t time_in_force;
    char trader_tag[4];
    uint8_t firm_id;
    char firm[257];//via
};

class OrderAck{
public:
    uint32_t order_id;
    uint64_t client_id;
    uint8_t order_status;
    uint8_t reject_code;
};

class OrderFill{
public:
    uint32_t order_id;
    uint64_t fill_price;
    uint32_t fill_qty;
    uint8_t no_of_contras;
//reapeating group ignored
};
#endif
```

**parser.h**

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

class Header;
class OrderAck;
class OrderFill;
class OrderEntry;

class Parser {
public:
    static void readHeader(Header& h, fstream& fin);
    static  void readOrderEntry(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderEntry& o);
    static  void readOrderAck(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderAck& o);
    static  void readOrderFill(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderFill& o);
private:
    static uint16_t readUInt16(char* buf);
    static uint16_t readUInt8(char* buf);
    static uint64_t readUInt64(char* buf);
    static uint32_t readUInt32(char* buf);
};

#endif
```

**parser.cpp**

```
#include "packets.h"
#include "parser.h"
//#define CHECK_BORDER
 void Parser::readHeader(Header& h, fstream& fin){
    char        buf[8];
    fin.read((char*)h.marker, 2);
    h.marker[2]        = 0;
    fin.read((char*)&h.msg_type, 1);
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    h.sequence_id          = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    h.timestamp        = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read((char*)&h.msg_direction, 1);
    fin.read(buf, 2);
    h.msg_len          = readUInt16(buf);
    }

 void Parser::readOrderEntry(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderEntry& o){
    char        buf[256+9];
    char term[9]           = "DBDBDBDB";
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    o.price            = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 4);
    o.qty              = readUInt32(buf);
    fin.read(o.instrument, 10);
    o.instrument[10]       = 0;
    fin.read((char*) &o.side, 1);
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    o.client_assigned_id   = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read((char*) &o.time_in_force, 1);
    fin.read(o.trader_tag, 3);
    o.trader_tag[3]        = 0;
    fin.read(buf, 1);
    o.firm_id          = readUInt8(buf);
    int     nread  = 0;
    char        c;
    while(fin.read((char*)&c, 1)){
        buf[nread++]       = c;
        if (nread >= 8) {
        int cnt    = 2;
        while(cnt<=8){
            if(buf[nread-cnt]=='D' && buf[nread-cnt+1]=='B')
            {
            cnt   += 2;
            } else {
            break;
            }
        }
        if (cnt>8) {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    int     i      = 0;
    for(; i<nread-8; i++){
        o.firm[i]          = buf[i];
    }
    o.firm[i]          = 0;
    }

 void Parser::readOrderAck(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderAck& o){
    char        buf[8];
    fin.read(buf, 4);
    o.order_id         = readUInt32(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    o.client_id        = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 1);
    o.order_status         = readUInt8(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 1);
    o.reject_code          = readUInt8(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 8);   //skip dbdbdbdb
#ifdef CHECK_BORDER
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i+=2){
        if(buf[i]!='D'&&buf[i+1]!='B'){
        printf("failed parse order fill\n");
        }
    }
#endif
    }

 void Parser::readOrderFill(uint16_t len, fstream& fin, OrderFill& o){
    char        buf[512];
    fin.read(buf, 4);
    o.order_id         = readUInt32(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 8);
    o.fill_price           = readUInt64(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 4);
    o.fill_qty         = readUInt32(buf);
    fin.read(buf, 1);
    o.no_of_contras        = readUInt8(buf);
    int     nread  = 0;
    char        c[9];
    for (int j = 0; j<o.no_of_contras; j++){
        fin.read((char*)c, 1);
        fin.read(c, 3);
        c[3]           = 0;
        fin.read(c, 4);
        uint32_t    qty    = readUInt32(c);
    }
    fin.read(c, 8);     // ignore terminated string
#ifdef CHECK_BORDER
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i+=2){
        if(c[i]!='D'&&c[i+1]!='B'){
        printf("failed parse order fill\n");
        }
    }
#endif
    }

uint16_t Parser::readUInt16(char* buf){

    uint16_t    b0, b1, res;
    b0             = buf[0];
    b1             = buf[1];
    res            = b0 | b1<<8;
    return res;
    }

uint16_t Parser::readUInt8(char* buf){

    uint16_t    b0, res;
    b0             = buf[0];
    res            = b0;
    return res;
    }

uint64_t Parser::readUInt64(char* buf){
    uint64_t    sum    = 0;
    uint64_t    b0     = buf[0],b1 = buf[1], b2 = buf[2], b3 = buf[3] ,b4=buf[4] ,b5=buf[5], b6=buf[6] ,b7=buf[7];
    sum            = b0 | b1<<8 | b2<<16 | b3<<24 | b4<<32 
        | b5<<40 | b6<<48 | b7<<56;
    return sum;


    }

uint32_t Parser::readUInt32(char* buf){
    uint64_t    sum    = 0;
    uint64_t    b0     = buf[0],b1 = buf[1], b2 = buf[2], b3 = buf[3];
    sum            = b0 | b1<<8 | b2<<16 | b3<<24;
    return sum;
}
```

**tradingsys.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "parser.h"
#include "packets.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //cout<<argv[1]<<endl;

    fstream fin(argv[1], ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);
    uint32_t total_packets = 0;
    uint32_t order_entry_msg_count = 0;
    uint32_t order_ack_msg_count = 0;
    uint32_t order_fill_msg_count = 0;
    std::map<string, uint32_t> activeTraderQty;
    std::map<string, uint32_t> GFDs;
    std::map<string, uint32_t> instrumentQty;
    string currentOrderInstrument;
    string currentTrader;

    while (!fin.eof()) {
    Header h;
    Parser::readHeader(h, fin);
    total_packets++;
    uint16_t len = h.msg_len;
    len = len -2 -1 -8 -8 -1 -2;
    if (h.msg_type == 1) { //order entry
        order_entry_msg_count++;
        OrderEntry orderEntry;
        Parser::readOrderEntry(len, fin, orderEntry);
        if(orderEntry.time_in_force == 2){
        string trader_tag(orderEntry.trader_tag);
        GFDs[trader_tag] += orderEntry.qty;
        }

        string instrument(orderEntry.instrument);
        currentOrderInstrument = instrument;
        string trader(orderEntry.trader_tag);
        currentTrader = trader;
        //printf("%s\n", currentTrader.c_str());

    } else if (h.msg_type == 2) { //order ack
        order_ack_msg_count++;
        OrderAck orderAck;
        Parser::readOrderAck(len, fin , orderAck);

    } else if (h.msg_type == 3) {
        order_fill_msg_count++;
        OrderFill orderFill;
        Parser::readOrderFill(len, fin, orderFill);
        instrumentQty[currentOrderInstrument] += orderFill.fill_qty;
        activeTraderQty[currentTrader] += orderFill.fill_qty;
        } else {

    }
    }


    uint32_t maxActiveQty = 0;
    string maxActiveTrader;
    for (std::map<string, uint32_t>::iterator it = activeTraderQty.begin(); it!=activeTraderQty.end(); ++it){
    if (it->second > maxActiveQty){
        maxActiveQty = it->second;
        maxActiveTrader = it->first;
    }
    }

    uint32_t maxVol = 0;
    string liquidityTrader;
    for (std::map<string, uint32_t>::iterator it = GFDs.begin(); it!=GFDs.end(); ++it){
    if (it->second > maxVol){
        maxVol = it->second;
        liquidityTrader = it->first;
    }
    }

    printf("%u, %u, %u, %u, %s, %s", total_packets, order_entry_msg_count, order_ack_msg_count, order_fill_msg_count, maxActiveTrader.c_str() ,liquidityTrader.c_str());

    for (std::map<string, uint32_t>::iterator it = instrumentQty.begin(); it!=instrumentQty.end(); ++it){
    printf(", %s : %u", it->first.c_str(), it->second);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
BINARIES = trading_sys

TRADING_SYS_SRCS = \
trading_sys.cpp    \
parser.cpp         \

BLDDIR = build

CC = g++
LD = g++
LDFLAGS = #-stdlib=libstdc++
CFLAGS =  #-stdlib=libstdc++

TRADING_SYS_OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BLDDIR)/%.o, $(TRADING_SYS_SRCS))

all: $(patsubst %, $(BLDDIR)/%, $(BINARIES))

clean:
    rm -f $(patsubst %, $(BLDDIR)/%, $(BINARIES))
    rm -f $(TRADING_SYS_OBJS)
    rmdir $(BLDDIR) || true

$(BLDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(BLDDIR)/trading_sys: $(TRADING_SYS_OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Why are you using classes for them and not structures ?

Comment: Your question will probably attract more attention and better answers if you add some description of what the program aims to achieve.

Comment: In reference to @JaDogg's comment -- in C++ `class`es and `struct`s are *the same*, it's just that in a `class` things are by default `private` and in a `struct` they're `public` by default. If you want everything `public`, a `struct` is appropriate. (But *why* do you want everything `public`?)

Comment: @Snowbody as you can see he/she already has everything in the classes public, I'm talking about `Header OrderAck OrderFill OrderEntry`  and not `Parser`

Answer (score 6):

I have found a couple of things that could help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  In particular you should never use it in a header file.

### Use the appropriate headers

Instead of using `stdint.h` you should instead use:

```
#include <cstdint>
```

This puts things from that header into the `std::` namespace instead of only into the global namespace and will save headaches later.  (Note that it *might* additionally put items into the global namespace, but as a programmer you should avoid relying on that implementation-defined behavior.)

### Eliminate unused variables

This code declares a number of variables (`term`, `qty`, `nread`) but then does nothing with them.  Your compiler is smart enough to help you find this kind of problem if you know how to ask it to do so.

### Avoid magic numbers

Lines that include numbers without explanation are a maintenance problem waiting to happen.  For example, the code includes this line with no comment:

```
len = len -2 -1 -8 -8 -1 -2;
```

It's probable that those aren't actually random but there is no hint as to the significance of those numbers.

### Don't use `while (!fin.eof())`

It's almost always an error to write code that uses `while (!fin.eof())` or the equivalent, because what you're interested in determining is if there is any *data* left and not whether it happens to be the end of the stream.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong?rq=1) for more details on that.

### Don't proliferate useless variables

The code currently includes this pair of lines:

```
string instrument(orderEntry.instrument);
currentOrderInstrument = instrument;
```

The `instrument` string is never used again.  Why not just write this instead?

```
currentOrderInstrument(orderEntry.instrument);
```

### Use appropriate control flow structures

Within `main`, the code decides how to handle the data based on the `msg_type` field.  It has a cascading `if...else` with an empty final `else` clause.  However, this would be much clearer written as a `switch` statement with each `case` representing a different message type.

### Use standard algorithms

The current code include this sequence:

```
uint32_t maxActiveQty = 0;
std::string maxActiveTrader;
for (std::map<std::string, uint32_t>::iterator it = activeTraderQty.begin(); it!=activeTraderQty.end(); ++it){
    if (it->second > maxActiveQty){
        maxActiveQty = it->second;
        maxActiveTrader = it->first;
    }
}
```

The purpose seems to be to identify the largest trading quantity and the associated trader.  However there is already an algorithm for this which is [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

### Use objects more completely

Your code has classes but they seem almost exclusively used a simple containters, such as `OrderEntry` and `OrderAck`.  It would make your code simpler and easier to understand and maintain if you also added member functions to them to do the things that are currently being done to these structures from within `main`.